# Enabling OS X 10.9 support on 10.8 (Mountain Lion)?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos

My MacBook Pro is running OS X 10.8 (Mountain Lion) and I have been literally advised by an authorised vendor not to install 10.9 due to its bugs.

(*I would appreciate not to be given the advise to upgrade to 10.9 or higher, that would be a major disruption for my system running bug-free for many years. That is not what I am asking and is not helpful in my case.*)

However,
 I have noticed the following entries in the **System Information** under *Software/Developer*:

```
SDKs:
  OS X:
  10.8: (12F37)
  10.9: (13C64)
```

Does this mean, some of the 10.9 functionalities are available on my machine that aren't currently enabled?

Is it possible to enable these, so that some 10.9 software can be used that currently refuses to install based on my OSX?

---

As an example, I wonder if that could help me install a more recent `C++`?

Comment: Even if it were possible, wouldn't these 10.9 functionalities contain the very bugs that you are worried about? If you want the features of an OS, you have to take the bugs as well. Mountain Lion is not 'bug-free'. ;-)

Comment: @benwiggy I am not worried about these bugs as I can easily disable the specific change causing them. Very different from new bugs or inefficiencies. And no, I don't want any feature if it comes with bugs. I haven't encountered any bugs on my 10.8 for many years, so for my purposes it is bug-free :)

Comment: @Tetsujin I respect your opinion, please kindly respect my request and don't comment if you cannot help. I have deleted my comments, as engaging in this discussion is of no help to me.

Comment: I removed all comments except this - in which I shall reiterate... you cannot build functionality from 10.9 into 10.8, no matter how many SKDs you have..

Answer (score 2):

Just because some of the SDK is there from 10.9 does not mean that you have enough of it to run 10.9 software.  So unfortunately you can either upgrade to 10.9 or sit it out on 10.8.

Comment: If these SDK allow me to develop for 10.9 on my machine, shouldn't they be capable of running some >=10.9 apps?

Comment: I think what you're asking is... if I have 10.9 SDKs on my computer will my computer act like 10.9 and the answer to that is no.  Installers that are built on 10.9 should not install on 10.8.  Its possible that some software is compatible for both but if you didn't have it on 10.8 then there is most likely a reason its not compatible.  If anything ... try it and see.

Comment: Look at it this way... you have enough of the SDKs to build cross-platform apps but not enough to run apps that are built for 10.9.  If you can find an old version of parallels or virtual box you might be able to run 10.9 there.

Comment: Thanks for your comments and sorry if my question is naive as I have no experience with OSX SDKs. Do I see it right that, with SDK provided, I can build my own 10.9 installers but cannot run them on my machine? Isn't it related to some build software, e.g. more recent C++ version? If yes, can I enable that version or check it somehow?

Comment: I have a VirtualBox installed but no experience using it, would you suggest any reference to learn how it could be used to run incompatible OS X software?

Comment: Dmitri... that is another question best asked on its own.